# Java: Read a word until space and store in array

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to write a program that can read two words separated by a space that is been entered by the user and store it in an array. So far, I only did this:

```
String[] wordsArray = new String[2];
System.out.print("Next, enter two words:");
wordsArray[0] = scannerlmao.nextLine();
wordsArray[1] = scannerlmao.nextLine();
System.out.println("You entered \"" + wordsArray[0] + "\" and \"" + wordsArray[1] + "\""); 

Input:
mike alpha

Expected output:
You entered "mike" and "alpha"

Issue:
You entered "" and "mike alpha"
```

Right now it only stored it on the second index of the array. I looked it up online but either for characters or numbers only showed up. Can we do it with this method or do we need a completely different way?

Comment: you only read one line. split that line, and store the results of that in wordsArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have just to use .next() instead of .nextLine()

next() : read the next word, but
nextLine(): read all the words entered in the same line.

```java
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scannerlmao = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] wordsArray = new String[2];
        System.out.print("Next, enter two words:");
        wordsArray[0] = scannerlmao.next();
        wordsArray[1] = scannerlmao.next();
        System.out.println("You entered \"" + wordsArray[0] + "\" and \"" + wordsArray[1] + "\"");
    }
}
```